# How to use database connection in threads?

Tags: python

I want to use standard database connections in threads. Is it thread-safe?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the particular database implementation you are using. If the module conforms to the [Python Database API Specification v2.0](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), it should have the `threadsafety` global that will let you know what can be shared between processes and what not. I guess if it is not 0, you can multi-thread at least some of your DB code.